# Adjusting mouse speed in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

how do I do this? Where is this adjustment located in Ubuntu?

Comment: Flavour? DE? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Top tight, where you woiuld restart or shutdown, just select "settings" and you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

The settings for adjusting the  mouse speed in Ubuntu 22.04 are located in *Settings* app-> *Mouse & Touchpad* as marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot.

[image]

You can also click the  <kbd>Test Your Settings</kbd>  button to test your mouse settings.